# change a character above certain pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
C        0.749421709   0.227878968   1.429202011   0.000039192  
C        1.632642695  -0.091443576   2.542631832  -0.000184939  
N        0.043615933   0.482209037   0.540453037   0.000123677   
H        2.515045687   0.527073165   2.500388888  -0.001989853   
H        1.941072900  -1.159598231   2.494001492   0.001039872   
H        1.143298831   0.111732200   3.499873978   0.001236466
```

which is a pattern that repeats several times across the entire file.
I need to change only the "C" right above the "N" for "Cn" in the entire file. I tried to use sed but none of the variations seem to work. I am able to find the pattern and add stuff either above or below, but I am not able to replace the "C" for "Cn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by reverse listing the original file

```
tac file | awk '/^N/ {NT = 1} /^C/ && NT {sub (/^C /, "Cn"); NT = 0} 1' | tac
```

Comment: it works very nicely and fast. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One solution :

```
tac file |
    awk '{if ($1=="C" && l=="N") $1="Cn"} {l=$1} 1' |
    tac |
    column -t
```

### Output

```
C   0.749421709  0.227878968   1.429202011  0.000039192
Cn  1.632642695  -0.091443576  2.542631832  -0.000184939
N   0.043615933  0.482209037   0.540453037  0.000123677
H   2.515045687  0.527073165   2.500388888  -0.001989853
H   1.941072900  -1.159598231  2.494001492  0.001039872
H   1.143298831  0.111732200   3.499873978  0.001236466
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in `sed` I think:

```
sed -e '$!N;/^C.*\nN/s/^C/Cn/' -e 'P;D' file
```

This maintains a 2-line buffer in pattern space and replaces a leading `C` if there is a `N` at the start of the second line.